# How to make a UITextView that selects a word upon a single touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView that is not editable but needs to be able to select a word upon a single touch of that word and have the selected word be passed on to another function. What's a way to go about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Superhacky solution (if you have a lot of words this is a bad bad idea):

- Make all words in `UITextView` links (but don't format them as such).
- Make your `UITextView` selectable in IB
- Have your VC (or whoever owns the UITextVeiw) to implement `UITextViewDelegate`
- Implement `-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange`
- Use the `characterRange` to set `UITextView` selectedTextRange
- Profit!

Less hacky solution would be to use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to get the tap location, translate it to `UITextView` and select the glyphs that horizontally surrond the tap location.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
    To get the selected string from textView, you have to implement `UITextViewDelegate` delegate and implement a method.

Step 2:
    pass the selectedText to another function

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.textView.delegate = self;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(textView: UITextView) {
        let range: NSRange = textView.selectedRange
        let text = textView.text as NSString
        let selectedText = text.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length))
        self.getSelectedText(selectedText)
    }

    func getSelectedText(text: String) {
        NSLog("\(text)")
    }
}
```